# How can I host angular configuration in GitHub Pages?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I've built an angular app from ngx-admin and deployed it to Github Pages.  Now I would like to have it run a specific configuration, e.g. `qa`, or `prod`.

When I run `npm run build:qa` -> `"build:qa": "npm run build -- --qa --aot",` I get the error:

```
Unknown option: '--qa'
```

... even though I have specified `qa` in angular.json:

```
"configurations": {
            "qa": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
```

Normally, from my local I use Node to serve the content via:

```
npm start:qa
```

Which calls the following configuration in package.json...

```
"start:qa": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --configuration=qa"
```

When I build the app, I specify:

```
npm run build:qa
```

Which calls the following configuration in package.json...

```
"build:qa": "npm run build -- --qa --aot"
```

The build fails.

Given that angular-cli.json is deprecated in Angular 7, how can I define my own build configurations, so I can host environment specific configurations without Node?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Angular 7 now supports `--configuration` in the declaration:

`"build:qa": "npm run build -- --configuration=qa --aot",`.

When I run `npm run build:qa` which calls `"build:qa": "npm run build -- --configuration=qa --aot",` in the `"scripts"` section of angular.json, I see the desired environment.qa.ts is properly swapped into place.

I believe what what confusing me is I specified `prod` in the `"configurations"` section of angular.json, and calling `npm run build -- --prod --aot` was failing to find `production`.  It would seem the key `production` is hard coded someplace in the Angular packages.

Answer (score 0):

Use this npm script

**"build:qa": "npm run build -- --configuration=qa --aot",**